# How do I conserve type using Observable.zip?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to apply `Observable.zip` to a list of observables. It works but I would like it to conserve the type information. The problem happens with the snippet below:

```
    val observable1 = Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
    val observable2 = Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)

    // result is a Array<Any>. Could it be an Array<Int> instead ?
    val result = Observable.zip(listOf(observable1, observable2), {a -> a}).blockingFirst()
```

It feels like `zip` should be able to know that my items are of type Int. In this very specific case, I could certainly cast but I also have more complex types and would feel much better if I could conserve type. Do I miss something ?

Comment: What happens when you change the observable expression to `Observable.zip( observable1, observable2, { o1, o2 -> listOf(o1,o2))` ?

Comment: I get `Cannot infer a type for this parameter on the zipper`, I have to explicitely set it as `BiFunction<Int, Int, List<Int>>{ o1, o2 -> listOf(o1,o2))}`
And in all cases, I need the List version as I want to zip an arbitrary number of observables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Java (and Kotlin) type system doesn't let you (or us library writers) do such type preservation; you have to manually cast back the `a` `Object[]` elements to their respective type.

This is done for you with the 2-9 argument `zip()` [overloads](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) and the `zipWith` instance operator.

The underlying problem is that one can't create a generic array as well as the type erasure itself. If we allowed `Function<T[], R>` in the signature, we would still have to create `new Object[]` for the invocation. However, your `Function<Integer[], R>` implementation would try to cast `Object[]` into `Integer[]` which is not allowed and fails with `ClassCastException`.

This is also described in the zip [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

> Note on method signature: since Java doesn't allow creating a generic array with new T[], the implementation of this operator has to create an Object[] instead. Unfortunately, a `Function<Integer[], R>` passed to the method would trigger a ClassCastException.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer ! And sorry for missing the javadoc.